# Change the size of a grid dynamically on select option change

Tags: angular, ng-class

I need some help regarding my form. I want that when the user selects other in a dropdown the size of the dropdown reduce from `class="col-sm-5"` to `class="col-sm-3"` and let an input type text appear.

```
                <div class="col-sm-5" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" *ngIf="selectedFormeJuridique !== 'other'">
                  <div ng-class="home">{{selectedFormeJuridique}}</div>
                  <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">Forme juridique</label>
                    <select ng-model="home" name="forme_juridique" class="form-control">
                      <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
                      <option value="sarl"> SARL</option>
                      <option value="sas"> SAS</option>
                      <option value="eurl"> EURL</option>
                      <option value="sasu"> SASU</option>
                      <option value="ae"> Auto-entrepreneur</option>
                      <option value="sa"> SA</option>
                      <option value="other"> AUTRE</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" *ngIf="selectedFormeJuridique === 'other'">
                  <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label">Entrer la forme juridique</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forme_juridique" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Don't mark questions as both Angular and AngularJS, they are different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass to change the class

```
[ngClass]="selectedFormeJuridique !== 'other' ? 'col-sm-3' : 'col-sm-5'"
```